# Why are my C programs running perfect in the compiler but the .exe of them runs then crashes?

Tags: c, crash

I have tried running the .exe of multiple programs that run and work perfect in my compiler (codeblocks) but when I run the .exe of the file they begin running but crash eventually. The .exe of this calculator for example crashes when it is supposed to display the answer, but works fine in my compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float Add(float num1, float num2){
    return num1 + num2;
}

float Subtract(float num1, float num2){
    return num1 - num2;
}

float Multiply(float num1, float num2){
    return num1 * num2;
}

float Divide(float num1, float num2){
    return num1 / num2;
}

int main()
{
    while(1){

        int selection;
        float num1, num2, answer;

        char* selectionNames[] = {"Addition", "Subtraction", "Multiplication", "Division"};
        printf("Select Function from List:\n1: Addition\n2: Subtraction\n3: Multiplication\n4:     Division\nSelection: ");
        scanf("%d", &selection);
        if(selection < 1 || selection > 4) {
            printf("Please choose a valid operator!");
            return 1;
        }
        if (selection == 0) {
            printf("Exiting...\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("You have Selected %s\n\n", selectionNames[selection-1]);

        printf("Enter First Number: ");
        scanf("%f", &num1);
        printf("Enter Second Number: ");
        scanf("%f", &num2);

        switch (selection){
        case 1:
            answer = Add(num1,num2);
            printf("\nAnswer = %.2f", answer);
            break;

        case 2:
            answer = Subtract(num1,num2);
            printf("\nAnswer = %.2f", answer);
            break;

        case 3:
            answer = Multiply(num1,num2);
            printf("\nAnswer = %.2f", answer);
            break;

        case 4:
            if (num2 == 0) {
                    printf("Cannot divide by zero!\n\n");
                    continue;
            }
            answer = Divide(num1,num2);
            printf("\nAnswer = %.2f", answer);
            break;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

The program works fine in my compiler but the .exe file for it crashes before it displays the answer, it takes 3 user inputs before the crash.

Comment: Try shifting the `\n` to the end of the `printf()` strings (the "conventional" way...) (And, maybe move `return 0` OUTSIDE of the `while()` loop, too.)

Comment: [cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/Eref4c5rW) a crash with correct dummy inputs. What are your inputs? What do you mean by "crash eventually"?

Comment: It works fine in my compiler, when I run the .exe of it found in the folder, it lets me select a mathematical function, allows me to input the first and second numbers, but then the console crashes (closes) before giving me the answer, which does not happen when I run it through my compiler. @yano

Comment: Thanks, I included them now @AndreasWenzel

Comment: Thanks that worked its running now! @Fe2O3

Comment: I see, probably mistaking program exit for a crash (as Fe2O3 correctly pointed out your misplaced `return 0`.

Comment: Does "running perfect in the compiler" mean "it compiles?" If so, there is a *lot* of code that compiles that has no hope of ever working out. Compiling does not check correctness. There's usually no such thing as "running in the compiler", that's called "compiling". The other part is called "executing" or, loosely, running your executable.

Comment: What do you mean by *crashes*?  Console programs open a console when they start and close it when they're done.  What happens when you open a console and call the program from whithin it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different problems:

1. Your program is supposed to run in a loop (why would there be a `while(1)` otherwise?), however, you have a `return` statement inside the loop block (just put it outside). Note that this isn't what is generally understood as "crashing", and its just a bug causing undesired behavior.
2. When you run a console application by clicking twice on it, the window will immediately close as soon as the program is done with its execution (which doesn't happen on your IDE because you have a permanent terminal). This abrupt window closing may be seem as a sign that the app is "crashing", but in this case it is not. It may be a good idea to add a simple prompt before the end of the program, to give your users a chance to read your program's last words:

```c
int main() {
  // ...
  printf("[press enter]");
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```